# how to get file name safetly and compare it in windows minifilter driver

Tags: windows, driver, minifilter, filter-driver

Hello i'm new at filterdriver writing so i'm apologizing for my basic question , i try to get the file name from a pre read function and check if it's equal to my file name and do some logic according to this info.

this is my function:

```
 FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS SwapPreReadBuffers(    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,    _Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID *CompletionContext   )
{
    PFLT_IO_PARAMETER_BLOCK iopb = Data->Iopb;
    FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS retValue = FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
    PVOID newBuf = NULL;
    PMDL newMdl = NULL;
    PVOLUME_CONTEXT volCtx = NULL;
    PPRE_2_POST_CONTEXT p2pCtx;
    NTSTATUS status;
    ULONG readLen = iopb->Parameters.Read.Length;
    PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION NameInfo = NULL;
    UNICODE_STRING FILE_NAME;

 //
 //  Skip IRP_PAGING_IO, IRP_SYNCHRONOUS_PAGING_IO and
 //  TopLevelIrp.
 //

    if ((Data->Iopb->IrpFlags & IRP_PAGING_IO) ||     (Data->Iopb->IrpFlags & IRP_SYNCHRONOUS_PAGING_IO) ||      IoGetTopLevelIrp())
    {
         return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
    }

    RtlInitUnicodeString( & FILE_NAME, L"my_file.txt" );

    status = FltGetFileNameInformation( Data,  FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED | 
    FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_DEFAULT, &NameInfo );
    if (!NT_SUCCESS( status )) 
    {
         DbgPrint("[-] SwapPreReadBuffers we couldn't extract %wZ info\n",  Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName);
    }


     status = FltParseFileNameInformation( NameInfo );
    if (!NT_SUCCESS( status )) 
     {
        DbgPrint("[-] SwapPreReadBuffers we couldn't pars %wZ info\n",  Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName);            
     }


     DbgPrint("[+] pars gets me Name: %wZ extention:  %wZ  perentDir: %wZ volume: %wZ \n",  NameInfo->Name, NameInfo->Extension, NameInfo->ParentDir, NameInfo->Volume);


    if (RtlPrefixUnicodeString( &FILE_NAME, &NameInfo->Name, TRUE ))        /* here i'm getting the blue screen*/
     {
         DbgPrint("[***] SwapPreReadBuffers we are at calles thats related to our file %wZ \n",  Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName);                
     }
    /* continue of the code*/
 }
```

my problem is i getting a blue screen when i try to check if the file name is equal to my wanted file name.
why the driver get here a blue screen?

Thank you
pit

edit:

i updated my code to this:

```
 FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS SwapPreReadBuffers(    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,    _Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID *CompletionContext   )
{
    PFLT_IO_PARAMETER_BLOCK iopb = Data->Iopb;
    FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS retValue = FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
    PVOID newBuf = NULL;
    PMDL newMdl = NULL;
    PVOLUME_CONTEXT volCtx = NULL;
    NTSTATUS CbStatus = FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
    PPRE_2_POST_CONTEXT p2pCtx;
    NTSTATUS status;
    ULONG readLen = iopb->Parameters.Read.Length;
    PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION NameInfo = NULL;
    UNICODE_STRING FILE_NAME;

 //
 //  Skip IRP_PAGING_IO, IRP_SYNCHRONOUS_PAGING_IO and
 //  TopLevelIrp.
 //

     if ((Data->Iopb->IrpFlags & IRP_PAGING_IO) ||
    (Data->Iopb->IrpFlags & IRP_SYNCHRONOUS_PAGING_IO) ||
    IoGetTopLevelIrp()) {

    DbgPrint("[-] SwapPreReadBuffers we out , this call not for us\n");
    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
}


status = FltGetFileNameInformation( Data,
                                    FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED
                                      | FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_DEFAULT,
                                    &NameInfo );
if (!NT_SUCCESS( status )) 
{
    DbgPrint("[-] SwapPreReadBuffers we couldn't extract info\n");
     goto PreReadCleanup;
}

status = FltParseFileNameInformation( NameInfo );
if (!NT_SUCCESS( status )) 
{
    DbgPrint("[-] SwapPreReadBuffers we couldn't pars info\n");
     goto PreReadCleanup;
}


if (NULL == NameInfo)
{
    DbgPrint("[---] name info is actally 0\n");
}
else
{
    DbgPrint("[*] address of name is %x:%x and address of extansion is %x:%x  -> buffers are: name %x  , extension: %x \nsize of info %d size of extension %d\n",NameInfo->Extension , &NameInfo->Extension, EXTENTION, &EXTENTION, NameInfo->Extension.Buffer , EXTENTION.Buffer ,NameInfo->Extension.Length , EXTENTION.Length);
}

if ((0 == RtlCompareUnicodeString( &EXTENTION, &NameInfo->Extension, TRUE ))) { 
    DbgPrint("[***] SwapPreReadBuffers we are at calles thats related to our file %wZ \n",  &Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName);  
    DbgPrint("[+] pass parse\n"); 
    DbgPrint("[+] pars gets me Name: %wZ\n extention:  %wZ\n  perentDir: %wZ\n volume: %wZ\n",  &NameInfo->Name, &NameInfo->Extension, &NameInfo->ParentDir, &NameInfo->Volume);
}
else{

    DbgPrint("[*] we pass compration check\n");
      goto PreReadCleanup;
}
 //
 //  Clean up
 //
 PreReadCleanup:
    if (NameInfo) {

        FltReleaseFileNameInformation( NameInfo );
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

and again i got a blue screen , this is the analized core dump:

```
    kd>  !analyze -v
    *******************************************************************************
    *                                                                             *
    *                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
    *                                                                             *
    *******************************************************************************

    PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50)
    Invalid system memory was referenced.  This cannot be protected by try-except,
    it must be protected by a Probe.  Typically the address is just plain bad or it
    is pointing at freed memory.
    Arguments:
    Arg1: 994af2a4, memory referenced.
    Arg2: 00000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation.
    Arg3: 82a72a17, If non-zero, the instruction address which referenced the bad memory
        address.
    Arg4: 00000000, (reserved)

    Debugging Details:
    ------------------


    READ_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from 829a5718
    Unable to read MiSystemVaType memory at 829851a0
     994af2a4 

    FAULTING_IP: 
    nt!RtlCompareUnicodeStrings+3c
    82a72a17 0fb706          movzx   eax,word ptr [esi]

    MM_INTERNAL_CODE:  0

    CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

    DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

    BUGCHECK_STR:  0x50

    PROCESS_NAME:  cmd.exe

    CURRENT_IRQL:  0

    TRAP_FRAME:  a72b7974 -- (.trap 0xffffffffa72b7974)
    ErrCode = 00000000
    eax=00000003 ebx=994af2aa ecx=8da2064c edx=000000bf esi=994af2a4 edi=137f5b5e
    eip=82a72a17 esp=a72b79e8 ebp=a72b79f4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac po nc
    cs=0008  ss=0010  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0030  gs=0000             efl=00010212
    nt!RtlCompareUnicodeStrings+0x3c:
    82a72a17 0fb706          movzx   eax,word ptr [esi]       ds:0023:994af2a4=????
    Resetting default scope

    LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 8287c3d8 to 828c941b

    STACK_TEXT:  
    a72b795c 8287c3d8 00000000 994af2a4 00000000 nt!MmAccessFault+0x106
    a72b795c 82a72a17 00000000 994af2a4 00000000 nt!KiTrap0E+0xdc
    a72b79f4 82a72b0f 994af2aa 00000003 acca4e02 nt!RtlCompareUnicodeStrings+0x3c
    a72b7a10 994a9105 994ad090 acca4d6c 00000001 nt!RtlCompareUnicodeString+0x25
    WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
    a72b7a6c 8b756aeb 87587068 a72b7a8c a72b7ab8 MyDriver2+0x1105
    a72b7ad8 8b7599f0 a72b7b2c 87435e48 00000000 fltmgr!FltpPerformPreCallbacks+0x34d
    a72b7af0 8b759f01 a72b7b2c 00000000 862ff240 fltmgr!FltpPassThroughInternal+0x40
    a72b7b14 8b75a3ba 032b7b00 862ff240 00000000 fltmgr!FltpPassThrough+0x203
    a72b7b44 82872593 862ff240 87435e48 87435e48 fltmgr!FltpDispatch+0xb4
    a72b7b5c 82a6699f 87435e48 87435fd8 87590d98 nt!IofCallDriver+0x63
    a72b7b7c 82a9f2da 862ff240 87590d98 00000001 nt!IopSynchronousServiceTail+0x1f8
    a72b7c08 828791ea 862ff240 87435e48 00000000 nt!NtReadFile+0x644
    a72b7c08 773e70b4 862ff240 87435e48 00000000 nt!KiFastCallEntry+0x12a
    0013f014 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0x773e70b4


    STACK_COMMAND:  kb

    FOLLOWUP_IP: 
    MyDriver2+1105
    994a9105 ??              ???

    SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  4

    SYMBOL_NAME:  MyDriver2+1105

    FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

    MODULE_NAME: MyDriver2

    IMAGE_NAME:  MyDriver2.sys

    DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  597b0358

    FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x50_MyDriver2+1105

    BUCKET_ID:  0x50_MyDriver2+1105

    Followup: MachineOwner
    ---------
```

so the crush is indead in the RtlCompareUnicodeString function (or in prefix version before) but i have no idea why it's crush there, it's look like i did every thing o.k.

Comment: in new code version: `RtlCompareUnicodeString( &EXTENTION, &NameInfo->Extension, TRUE )` - where `EXTENTION` is initialized and how ? bugcheck show that `Buffer` (`0x994af2a4`) is invalid. this can be in `EXTENTION` (i guess) or in `&NameInfo->Extension`. and your dbgprint (new version) anyway wrong

Comment: `EXTENTION` is a global varible and it's initialized in driver entry (the initialization went fine , i print in driver entry the value of extention after initialization to make shure that it's went fine.

Comment: (i also tried to use the cancelSafe minifilter from microsoft as is without any change and it's also bsod me in the same function with the same error (some address is unvalid)) ( the cencel safe code can be found here https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/cancelSafe)

Comment: your Bugcheck Analysis clear show that `Buffer` in `NameInfo->Extension` or `EXTENTION` is invalid. or or. if you more deep look for crash dump - this is easy view exactly. the `NameInfo->Extension` is initialized by fltmgr and i doubt that it can invalid (if you show all code as is and not damage it in code which you not show). `EXTENTION is initialized in driver entry` - not with local string ? not overwrite it late ? and fix at the and dbgprint - almost all it wrong. when you pass `UNICODE_STRING` as argument

Comment: i initialized it from driver entry  like this `  RtlInitUnicodeString( &EXTENTION, L"txt" );`

Comment: in this case only one option - need analyze crash dump

Comment: i added the crash dump , how can i learn from that what exactly the problem and how to fix it? (sorry if this question is dumb , i very new to the kernel world programming) @RbMm

Comment: in kernel dump all visible (your crash very simply for research). if look callstack, registers.. we can view which exactly unicode string is invalid, etc. but need know assembly, and be able read and research crash dump

Answer (score 1):

your bug not in call `RtlPrefixUnicodeString( &FILE_NAME, &NameInfo->Name, TRUE ))` - here all ok. your bug in previous line:

```
DbgPrint("[+] pars gets me Name: %wZ extention:  %wZ  perentDir: %wZ volume: %wZ \n",  
NameInfo->Name, 
NameInfo->Extension, 
NameInfo->ParentDir, 
NameInfo->Volume);
```

the `%wZ` format require **pointer** to `UNICODE_STRING` - so must be

```
DbgPrint("[+] pars gets me Name: %wZ extention:  %wZ  perentDir: %wZ volume: %wZ \n",  
&NameInfo->Name, 
&NameInfo->Extension, 
&NameInfo->ParentDir, 
&NameInfo->Volume);
```

also if `FltGetFileNameInformation` fail - you must not use `NameInfo` after that (it will be 0 or undefined). but you not do this in code

and usually swap buffers need do when and only when `Data->Iopb->IrpFlags & IRP_NOCACHE` - so when data readed or writed to storage

Comment: Thank you ver much

Comment: i changed my code , but still i am out with a blue screen when RtlPrefixUnicodeString presents ( i don't get a blue screen when i comment it out, so i believe this is the source of the problem)

Comment: @pit - you need analyze crash dump for view exactly source of problem. `DbgPrint` when you pass `UNICODE_STRING` instead of `UNICODE_STRING*` of course error. in `RtlPrefixUnicodeString( &FILE_NAME, &NameInfo->Name, TRUE )` no error, if `NameInfo != 0`. but in this case you will be crash before (how i say you need correct handle fail of `FltGetFileNameInformation`

Comment: @pit - and all your `DbgPrint` where `%wZ` is wrong. you every time pass `UNICODE_STRING` instead of `UNICODE_STRING*` - `Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName` for example

Comment: i fixed the dbgprints to `&NameInfo->Name` so all of them are pointers now , and i added return on every `!NT_SUCCESS( status )` case , when i comment out only the `RtlPrefixUnicodeString( &FILE_NAME, &NameInfo->Name, TRUE )` im good , but when there is this comper , i get a blue screen so i think it's have to be something to do with this no?

Comment: also i'm runing on win7 32bit in case  this is relevant

Comment: @pit - you must not think. you must analyze crash dump

Comment: i added the crush dump and the new written code to the original post

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of mistakes here.

1. First of all don't print things that could be NULL, check them first.
   Go through the **FLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION** structure and make sure all the data you want to print is actually there.
2. Fix your symbols in the debugger. Make sure your debugger has the symbol path set to the folder where your .pdb is.
3. Don't query the name in PreRead. There are several reasons not to do this, but I will tell you what you should do:
4. 1. In Post **IRP_MJ_CREATE** query the name of the file that has been opened. Check if it is the file you are interested in. If no, just return flt postop finished processing otherwise, if it is a file you are interested in create a context for it and store the FileNameInformation there as well while you're at it.
5. 1. Now in PreRead, when you are called simply ask for the context of the file object. If one is present, that means it is a file you are interested in so then you do your processing, otherwise you simply skip the read.
6. Be aware of string processing routines and IRQL. Don't use static stack strings for comparison like L"my_file.txt"

Also please show how your variable EXTENSION is initialized.